# Fork project or start new one is best to do

Tags: web, git-fork

i  am working on a website using polymer using Git ,now i need to remove and add feature to the website

so is the best way to do that :

- forking the old website and edit/add/ remove feature .
- starting new website from zero.

i was thing if i chose to fork i will get lot of messy code so what should i do?

Comment: Please be more specific about your [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) perhaps it is `git`? If so it doesn't sound that you're familiar with branching concept from your question. Please read about [git basic branching](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) then revise your question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself an structure plan [draw.io](http://www.draw.io)
and think if you can create something like an internal api ( maybe overkill) or create modules of your features

Create an adittional diagram of your features and where these have connections to others.

Now create the fork and prepare your work before you implement new features

If your project gets bigger you maybe should get yourself an structure like the v-model